# Creating a custom website audience and prefilling with past data

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

We'd like to create a custom audience, based on website pixel data. This should be prefilled with past visitors that match the criteria

Here's an example which does this, but does not prefil

```
$set = new CustomAudience(null, $account_id);
$set->setData(array(
CustomAudienceFields::ID,
CustomAudienceFields::NAME =>"Test audience",
CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION =>"Test audience from API",
  CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE =>'WEBSITE',
 CustomAudienceFields::RULE => '{ 
  "event": {
    "i_contains": "ViewEvent" 
  }
}',
CustomAudienceFields::RETENTION_DAYS =>90


));

$set->create();
```

What needs to be passed through to trigger the prefil? The docs specify a 'prefil' parameter for curl calls but I cant see the relevant field in the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

This was missing from the SDK until last night when we patched to add this feature.

You can now just add the parameter: `CustomAudienceFields::PREFILL => true` and everything should work!

```
$set->setData(array(
  CustomAudienceFields::ID,
  CustomAudienceFields::NAME =>"Test audience",
  CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION =>"Test audience from API",
  CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE =>'WEBSITE',
  CustomAudienceFields::RULE => '{ 
    "event": {
      "i_contains": "ViewEvent" 
     }
  }',
  CustomAudienceFields::RETENTION_DAYS =>90,
  CustomAudienceFields::PREFILL => true,
));
```